# Rails routes/show error - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reviews"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails development.

I have created a new database model called review and a controller called reviews_controller. In my routes file I have created the resource for reviews. However when I try and use the reviews#show in a link I get the error. No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reviews"}.

I have looked this error up but any of the results that I have found are more involved than the code that I am using. Is there something very basic that I am missing here.

Code for the model is

```
    class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    end
```

Code for the controller is

```
    class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @review = Reviews.find(params[:id])
      end

    def new
    end
    end
```

My link to in my header partial is

```
    <li><%= link_to "Review", review_path %></li>
```

Code from my routes file

```
     resources :users      #New Line
     resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
     resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
     resources :reviews
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I cant get anywhere on this.

Comment: Are you missing @review in your review path?  review_path(@review)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Since you are linking to a specific review, you need to pass in the review's id to the link_to method.

```
<li><%= link_to "Review", review_path(@review) %></li>
```

Rails is smart enough to take the whole @review object to figure out its id.

Alternatively, you can link to all your reviews with

```
<li><%= link_to "Reviews", reviews_path %></li>
```

Since you said you have this link in your header partial, this might be what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is some user/logging functionality included in the application. When I logged in and used the <li><%= link_to "Review", review_path(@review) %></li> code it has corrected the problem. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I have another issue with this now.

Comment: The reviews show page is working but most of the other links now give the error matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reviews"} including a link to a static web page. Takeing out the link to the reviews show view corrects this.